# Quantum Program The name 'BellTest' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, quantum-computing, q#

This is my first Q# program and i'm following this getting started link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-writeaquantumprogram?view=qsharp-preview

Error is

> The name 'BellTest' does not exist in the current context 
>   but its defined in the Bell.cs

I followed the steps and when building its having errors. I'm not sure how to import the operations from `.qs file` to driver `c# file` as this error looks like it can't find that operation.

Any help is really appreciated

Here is the code

Driver.cs

```
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

namespace Quantum.Bell
{
    class Driver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var sim = new QuantumSimulator())
            {
                // Try initial values
                Result[] initials = new Result[] { Result.Zero, Result.One };
                foreach (Result initial in initials)
                {
                    var res = BellTest.Run(sim, 1000, initial).Result;
                    var (numZeros, numOnes) = res;
                    System.Console.WriteLine(
                        $"Init:{initial,-4} 0s={numZeros,-4} 1s={numOnes,-4}");
                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            System.Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Bell.qs

```
namespace Quantum.Bell
{
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;

    operation Set (desired:Result,q1:Qubit) : ()
    {
        body
        {

             let current = M(q1);

            if (desired != current)
            {
                X(q1);
            }

        }
    }

    operation BellTest (count : Int, initial: Result) : (Int,Int)
    {
        body
        {
            mutable numOnes = 0;
            using (qubits = Qubit[1])
            {
                for (test in 1..count)
                {
                    Set (initial, qubits[0]);

                    let res = M (qubits[0]);

                    // Count the number of ones we saw:
                    if (res == One)
                    {
                        set numOnes = numOnes + 1;
                    }
                }
                Set(Zero, qubits[0]);
            }
            // Return number of times we saw a |0> and number of times we saw a |1>
            return (count-numOnes, numOnes);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I received that error a couple of times when I had a compile error in the q# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got the same error, but I was able to do it by pressing the `F5` key.

Perhaps the Visual Studio editor is not yet fully support to the `.qs` file.
Namespace sharing does not seem to be working properly between `.cs` file and `.qs` file.

I was able to execute using your code in my development environment.

--

IDE: Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.5.2)
Dev Kit: Microsoft Quantum Development Kit (0 and 1)

Comment: thank you i reinstalled the kit and it worked...not sure what was the reason

Comment: I have the latest build and I get the same error on VisualStudioCode and template `0.3.1810.2508-preview"`. `F5` does not help actually.

Answer (score 2):

I engage the same problem in microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.3.1811.203-preview version.

The BellTest operation cannot recognised by VSC [Pic of VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHft8.png)

What I do is,

1. save all but keep VSCode open
2. go to directory and delete anything in bin/ obj/  by /bin/rm -rf bin obj
3. dotnet run
4. you go back to check VSCode, the BellTest recognised by VSC now.